# Simulation doesn't run for the determined 10 seconds

Tags: networking, simulation, ns2

This simulation is set to work for 10 seconds but stops at 4.5 when the FTP is supposed to start sending packets. would you please help me fix it?
I have been working with NS2 for 3 hours. I am a hell of a noob right now.

```
#Creating a simulator object
set ns [new Simulator]
global $ns
set traceFile [open output.tr w]
$ns trace-all $traceFile
set namFile [open output.nam w]
$ns namtrace-all $namFile

#Defining the finish procedure
proc finish {} {
  global ns namFile traceFile fert
  $ns flush-trace

  close $namFile
  close $traceFile

  exec nam output.nam &
  exit 0
}

set n0 [$ns node]
set n1 [$ns node]
set n2 [$ns node]
set n3 [$ns node]
set n4 [$ns node]
set n5 [$ns node]
set n6 [$ns node]
#for {set i 0} {$i<5} {incr i} {
#set n($i) [$ns node]
#}

#Creating the links
$ns duplex-link $n0 $n1 1Mb 20ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n0 $n2 1Mb 20ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n1 $n3 1Mb 20ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n2 $n3 1Mb 20ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n2 $n4 1Mb 20ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n2 $n6 1Mb 20ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n4 $n6 1Mb 20ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n4 $n5 1Mb 20ms DropTail

#Topology
$ns duplex-link-op $n0 $n1 orient down 
$ns duplex-link-op $n0 $n2 orient right  
$ns duplex-link-op $n1 $n3 orient right  
$ns duplex-link-op $n2 $n3 orient down 
$ns duplex-link-op $n2 $n4 orient right 
$ns duplex-link-op $n2 $n6 orient right-down
$ns duplex-link-op $n4 $n5 orient right-down 
$ns duplex-link-op $n4 $n6 orient down 

#Agents - Attach Agents - SInk and Null connetions
set udp0 [new Agent/UDP]
set tcp3 [new Agent/TCP]
set null4 [new Agent/Null]
set sink5 [new Agent/TCPSink]
$ns attach-agent $n0 $udp0
$ns attach-agent $n3 $tcp3
$ns attach-agent $n4 $null4
$ns connect $udp0 $null4
$ns connect $tcp3 $sink5


#CBR over UDP connection
set cbr0 [new Application/Traffic/CBR]
$cbr0 attach-agent $udp0
$cbr0 set type_ CBR
$cbr0 set packet_size_ 1500
$cbr0 set rate_ 830kb


#FTP over TCP connection
set ftp3 [new Application/FTP]
$ftp3 attach-agent $tcp3
$ftp3 set type_ FTP

#Queue Limit of n2-n4 and n4-n5
$ns queue-limit $n2 $n4 30
$ns queue-limit $n4 $n5 20

#Assigning a link variable for the link between n4 and n5



#Monitoring
set mon [open "mon.txt" w]
set qmon [$ns monitor-queue $n2 $n4 $mon 0.01]
[$ns link $n2 $n4] queue-sample-timeout
#set qmon24 [$ns monitor-queue $n2 $n4 "" 0.01]

#............................................
    set link01 [$ns link $n2 $n3]
# Create monitor 
    set fmonitor [$ns makeflowmon Fid]
    $ns attach-fmon $link01 $fmonitor
        set drop_count [$fmonitor set parrivals_]

#............................................
proc mon { } { 
global ns qmon 
set t [$ns now] 
puts "$t [$qmon set pkts_]" 

$ns at [expr $t + 0.5] "mon" 
}

#Link Down and Up at 5.0 and 7.0

        $ns rtmodel-at 5.0 down $n2 $n4
        $ns rtmodel-at 7.0 up $n2 $n4

#$ns rtproto LS

$ns at 0 "mon"

$ns color cbr "red"


$ns at 2.0 "$cbr0 start"
$ns at 4.5 "$ftp3 start"
$ns at 8.0 "$cbr0 stop"
$ns at 9.0 "$ftp3 stop"

$ns at 10.0 "finish"

$ns run
```

And another question. What is a link queue? I gotta monitor the queue of a link between two nodes for my project but I don't understand the concept of a link queue! oh and one more thing. The Nam doesn't start automatically and I get this:

Classfier::no-slot{} default handler (tcl/lib/ns-lib.tcl) ---
    _o21: no target for slot 4294967295
    _o21 type: Classifier/Hash/Dest
content dump:
classifier _o21
    0 offset
    0 shift
    1073741823 mask
    1 slots
        slot 3: _o196 (Classifier/Port)
    -1 default

Comment: Links INFO: ns2 documentation https://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/doc/index.html ... I can make a version of your file to get a result https://www.dropbox.com/s/4nql1eljfekk7xm/Aramesh-ns2.tcl?dl=0 ... But nam fails: `class Animator: constructor failed: class NetworkModel: constructor failed: error when calling class NetworkModel: link 1 0 1.0 20.0 0 0.5` ... ( output.nam = 159kB ). ... The set simulation time is maximum time.

Comment: ns2 is old. Some files can run with an old OS. Your original code runs better with the 32bits `Ubuntu 10.10 - i386` : output.nam = 238kB. ... `$ nam output &` ... shows https://www.dropbox.com/s/3doe3glu8cglq3s/nam-output.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

> Classfier::no-slot{} default handler

The error  "Classfier::no-slot{} default handler .."  indicate coding errors (or a too complex file.)
Besides that, the error causes the simulation not to finish.

EDIT : The typical ways to have "mixed traffic" → cbr, tcp, udp, ftp ... see examples https://www.dropbox.com/s/63ultpb20ugqlvf/new-A-ex.tar.gz?dl=0

A primitive fix : With ftp entries commented out, your simulation ends OK, and the NAM window opens. Snippet :

```
#FTP over TCP connection
#set ftp3 [new Application/FTP]     ;# edited
#$ftp3 attach-agent $tcp3           ;# edited
#$ftp3 set type_ FTP                ;# edited
.
#$ns at 4.5 "$ftp3 start"   ;# edited 
$ns at 8.0 "$cbr0 stop"
#$ns at 9.0 "$ftp3 stop"    ;# edited
```

Simulation :

```
$ ns 3-no-ftp__2Aramesh.tcl
0 0
0.5 0
1 0
1.5 0
2 0
2.5 0
3 0
3.5 0
4 1
4.5 0
5 -4
5.5 -4
6 -4
6.5 -4
7 -4
7.5 -3
8 -4
8.5 -4
9 -4
9.5 -4
```

Files created: mon.txt 1001 lines, output.nam 514.7kB, output.tr 203.7kB .

"Link queue" ns2 doc 49.2.2 https://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/doc/node634.html

Note : The time you have set is maximum time.
If a simulation finishes in two seconds, no time setting will extend the actual simulation time.